# Android in-App selling of physical products outside US

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

I am looking for all possible ways to sell physical products or services via android App on Google Play. I was following the tutorial for Wallet Intant Buy that allows it in https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial?hl=es, but after filling the Intant Buy Register Form I have received a mail saying merchants must: "Sell items in the United States (Instant Buy cannot be used to make sales outside of the US at this time)"

My company is established in Europe and is where we plan to sell products, which alternatives do we have? As I have readed PayPal SDK option is not allowed to Google Play Apps.
Another option we consider is embbed the shopping cart via WebView component, is that possible in a Google Play App? We obviously prefer native alternatives.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Jesus if you found out a tool for outside US, please let me know, I am looking as well

Comment: Jesús, @Saher I am also looking for such a solution.

Comment: @user919426 my question is still open, I am still looking for that